# Different data sizes in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

Tags: mysql, database-performance, amazon-aurora

I'm trying to understand if the table is being loaded to InnoDB buffer. For that I'm querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE table.
From what I see, the table is fully loaded. However, amount of data loaded (MB) into buffer is very different from the numbers displayed in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.

For example:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_ROWS
    , CAST(DATA_LENGTH/POWER(1024,2) AS DECIMAL(5, 0)) AS DATA_LENGTH_MB
    , CAST(DATA_FREE/POWER(1024,2) AS DECIMAL(5, 0)) AS DATA_FREE_MB
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '<db_name>' 
        AND TABLE_NAME = '<table_name>';


| TABLE_NAME   | TABLE_ROWS | DATA_LENGTH_MB | DATA_FREE_MB |
|-----------------------------------------------------------|
| <table_name> | 39735968   | 10516          | 548          |
```

So there is around 39.7 million records and 10.5 GB in data pages according to INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

However, when I'm running this:

```
SELECT p.TABLE_NAME, p.INDEX_NAME
    , ROUND(SUM(DATA_SIZE)/POWER(1024,2)) AS DATA_SIZE_MB
    , SUM(NUMBER_RECORDS) AS NUMBER_RECORDS
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE AS p 
WHERE p.TABLE_NAME LIKE '`<db_name>`.`<table_name>`' AND p.INDEX_NAME = 'PRIMARY' 
    AND p.PAGE_TYPE = 'INDEX' AND p.PAGE_STATE = 'FILE_PAGE'
ORDER BY p.TABLE_NAME, p.INDEX_NAME
```

I'm getting:

```
| TABLE_NAME             | INDEX_NAME | DATA_SIZE_MB | NUMBER_RECORDS |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| <db_name>.<table_name> | PRIMARY    | 3505         | 45224835       |
```

And finally,

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM <db_name>.<table_name>;
44947428
```

NUMBER_RECORDS is slightly greater that TABLE_ROWS in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES. so I assume that table is fully loaded into memory, and TABLE_ROWS is either approximate or not up to date.
But why DATA_SIZE in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE is so much different (3.5 GB vs. 10.5 GB) ?
What am I missing? Is the data size in TABLES completely incorrect?

Database is running on Amazon RDS (Aurora MySQL 5.7) if that matters.

Thanks.

P.S. CREATE TABLE statement (columns names obfuscated, sorry : )

```
CREATE TABLE `table_name` (
    `recid` BINARY(32) NOT NULL,
    `col1` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `col2` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `col3` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `col4` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `col5` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `col6` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `col7` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `col8` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `col9` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `col10` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `col11` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `col12` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `col13` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `col14` INT(11) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `col15` BINARY(32) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `col16` CHAR(2) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `col17` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `col18` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `col19` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `col20` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`recid`) USING BTREE,
    UNIQUE INDEX `col3` (`col3`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `col5` (`col5`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `col8` (`col8`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  In particular, I want know if there are `TEXT` or `BLOB` columns.

Comment: What do you get from SELECT p.TABLE_NAME, p.INDEX_NAME     , page_type, page_state, ROUND(SUM(DATA_SIZE)/POWER(1024,2)) AS DATA_SIZE_MB     , SUM(NUMBER_RECORDS) AS NUMBER_RECORDS FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE AS p  WHERE p.TABLE_NAME LIKE '...' GROUP BY 1,2,3,4 ORDER BY p.TABLE_NAME, p.INDEX_NAME;

Comment: CREATE TABKE statement attached above. There are no BLOB or TEXT columns

The output from your statement:
TABLE_NAME   | INDEX_NAME | page_type | page_state | DATA_SIZE_MB | NUMBER_RECORDS
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<table_name> | PRIMARY    | INDEX     | FILE_PAGE  | 1461         | 19111932


Looks like around 50% of te table was removed since last time

Comment: Aurora has some significant differences; I don't know if they are relevant.  The variation in num-rows does not worry me, but "3.5 GB vs. 10.5 GB" does seem quite significant (and cannot be explained by anything in my Answer, even with hand-waving).

Comment: What is the average size of those VARCHARs?  The max for a row is not much over 2K, even assuming 3-byte utf8 chars being used throughout -- 90GB total.  I would _guess_ that a row is typically 350 bytes 16GB total.  (This assumes mostly 1-byte chars, and varchars are not very full.)  So, your 10.5GB is close, but the 3.5GB implies either that your varchars are awfully empty or 3.5 is awfully low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for a long delay. I have finally managed to confirm there in fact was a data clean-up performed on the table in question. Around 60% or the records were deleted.
That should explain the difference between **size** and **n_leaf_pages** values in **mysql.innodb_index_stats** table. Not sure if that's normal behavior or not.

SO to answer my ow question. To estimate how much table would take in InnoDB pool I should probably be looking into **mysql.innodb_index_stats**.**size** instead of **INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE**.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, ROUND((stat_value*@@innodb_page_size)/POWER(1024,2)) AS DATA_SIZE_MB 
FROM mysql.innodb_index_stats 
WHERE database_name = 'db_name' AND index_name = 'PRIMARY' AND table_name = 'table_name' 
    AND stat_name = 'n_leaf_pages';
```

Thanks @Rick James for helping me with this one

Answer (score 0):

> The Information Schema INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE table contains information about pages in the buffer pool.

Note the last 4 words.

That suggests that SUM from `INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE` may be smaller than what you get from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`.

(I don't know all the details, but here are some general statements.)

The buffer_pool may contain:

- Some or all of the leaf nodes for a table.
- Some or all of the non-leaf nodes for a table.
- Ditto for leaf and non-leaf nodes for each non-PRIMARY index for a table.
- Ditto for more tables.
- TEXT and BLOB (*and* large VARCHAR) may be stored off-record.  This greatly increases the disk space occupied.  But I don't think this happens in your case.  *However, see below*.
- 25% (tunable) of the buffer_pool is reserved for the "change buffer"; this is sort of a write cache for changes to secondary indexes.
- Other stuff
- A few percent of the buffer_pool is held in reserve or lost for other reasons.

Blocks are kicked out of the buffer_pool in [roughly] a least-recently-used order.

I don't know, but I would expect that it might not be possible to keep a table in the buffer_pool if that table is half the size of the buffer_pool.

Another thing to note...  The Data_free metric for each table is just one of quite a few categories of "overhead" in a table.

- Pre-allocated blocks (perhaps reflected in Data_free)
- Unfilled blocks (perhaps no data or index block is 100% full)
- Transactions lead to extra copies of rows -- these come and go, either in the undo/redo space or in the data blocks.
- Block splits
- etc.
- A Rule of Thumb is that the disk space occupied by the data  (Data_length) is 2x-3x the predicted size.  ("Predicted" = adding up individual data sizes, such as 4 bytes for each `INT`.)

**Wild idea**

What is the `ROW_FORMAT`?

Your 3.5GB computation may be the on-record space, and *all* the `VARCHARs` are stored off_record.  The math almost works out.

Let's pursue 2 avenues of thought with

```
SELECT count(*),
       AVG(LENGTH(col3)) AS avg3,
       AVG(LENGTH(col5)) AS avg5,
       ...   -- the rest of the VARCHARs
    FROM table_name;
```

(I specifically want `LENGTH()`, not `CHAR_LENGTH()`.)

Comment: Well, I was expecting that the numbers for a table FULLY loaded into memory would pretty close. But now it's somewhere between 30 and 60 % of the table size on disk.
My ultimate goal is to estimate how much of the tables can be loaded into memory. But at this moment I can't see a way to do that, given that numbers are so much different

Comment: @RimvydasGurskis - I provided some more hand-waving in my answer.  Good luck.  Please publish your findings, either here or in some form of blog.

Comment: ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic

Comment: Here are the averages:
count(*)     | col3      | col5       |  col8      | col11 | col18
47074590  | 6.0000 | 22.3948 | 11.0000 | (null) | 7.2727
Given current size (3.8 GB) average row length is around 80 bytes. That kind of makes sense, because around half of the columns allow NULLs

Comment: Numbers is **mysql.innodb_index_stats** look strange to me. There is a big difference between size and n_leaf_pages values.
SELECT stat_name, stat_value, ROUND((stat_value*@@innodb_page_size)/POWER(1024,2)) AS DATA_SIZE_MB   
from mysql.innodb_index_stats 
where database_name = 'db_name' AND index_name = 'PRIMARY' AND table_name = 'table_name' 
 AND stat_name IN ('size','n_leaf_pages' );

Comment: `stat_name      | stat_value  | DATA_SIZE_MB`
`n_leaf_pages | 242987      | 3797`
`size                |673020       | 10516`

Comment: My guess is that the table was taking 10.5 GB initially. Then a large part was deleted. But space allocated initially was never released. Table rebuild should fix this, but I don't want to do that on production environment (just yet :) ).

Comment: Hmmm...  The AVGerages say that there are _probably_ no off-record storage.  That is, probably all the data for a given row is inside a single block.  Back to scratching my head.